# Why do I have a different user name on Meta than I do on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, linked-accounts, display-names

I changed my username a while back from Tyrannosaurs to Jon Hopkins.

Jon Hopkins shows everywhere on SE except Meta Stack Overflow which is still showing Tyrannosaurs.  When I look at the profile all the accounts are linked (and show as Jon Hopkins) so not clear why this should be.

Am I missing something?  Obviously not actually important but odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accounts, while linked, are separate so if you change your name on one it won't automatically update on all the others. This is why the names are still different on your SO and MSO accounts.

If you've been a user of MSO from the very beginning then your SO and MSO user ids will be the same because Jeff copied the SO data when setting up MSO. On all other sites your user id will be different as it's allocated when you first log in.

Did you change the name **before** you created the other SE accounts? When you create a new SE account it copies the profile from the highest reputation profile.

You can copy the information by going to your Stack Overflow profile (say) and clicking on <kbd>Copy Stack Overflow Profile to Related Accounts</kbd>. This will have the effect of updating your profile as well as your name.

Or you can just go into your Meta profile and change the name there ;)

Comment: Ah, this is it.  Skimming the names they all looked the same but then I noticed that for my SF and SU accounts (which would have existed before the change) those two had the name JonHopkins (no space).  This suggests that I'd changed them myself (and messed up doing so) but that I didn't do meta....