# Propagate display name change to all associated accounts

Tags: support, linked-accounts, display-names

If I change my display name on (for example) Stack Overflow, my old display name is still shown on Meta Stack Overflow. Is there a way to propagate the change to all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different user name on Meta and SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79507/different-user-name-on-meta-and-so)

Answer (score 6):

Scroll down to the bottom of the profile edit form and click **Copy Profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts**. This should be sufficient for you, given that there's nothing else in your profile except your display name that could possibly be overwritten.

It doesn't propagate by default because some people like to [maintain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) [identities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7364/the-annoying-pyro) on various sites for various reasons.

Comment: Or, you know, it could be an undiagnosed case of multiple personality disorder that obviously few are concerned enough about to rat on besides said divided personalities.

Comment: Hey, you're not allowed out of the box for another hour.  Get back in there so pollyanna has a turn.